# Laravel migrate one to one relationships error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, migrate

I have a question regarding laravel migration table. I have a relation one to one between 2 tables. OrderLine and Ticket. I have put these 2 function in the model Ticket and OrderLine:

```
public function orderline()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\OrderLine');

} 

public function ticket()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Ticket');
}
```

and in migrations file create_tickets_table the Schema :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('order_line_id')->unsigned(); //foreign key
        $table->string('number');
        $table->float('price');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('order_line_id')->references('id')->on('order_lines');//relationship  one to one between orderline & ticket tables
    });
}
```

and in migrations file create_order_lines_table the Schema :

```
  public function up()
{
    Schema::create('order_lines', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('ticket_id')->unsigned();//foreign key
        $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned(); //foreign key
        $table->float('total_order_line');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('ticket_id')->references('id')->on('tickets');//relationship  one to one between orderline & ticket tables

        $table->foreign('order_id')// relationship one to many between order & order line tables
        ->references('id')->on('orders')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

and when i do php artisan migrate I still have have this error :

bruno@bruno-HP-EliteBook-840-G4:~/projetconcert$ php artisan migrate
Migration table created successfully.

Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `gestion_concert_spectacle`.`#sql-e08_30d` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `order_lines` add constraint `order_lines_ticket_id_foreign` foreign key (`ticket_id`) references `tickets` (`id`))

Does somebody have any idea how to solve it ? Thank you. Bruno

Comment: why do you use foreign in your ticket and your order lines id... you only need to use one foreign.. you are using relation,, so whenever you use in ticket or in order lines.. you can get them with the same id.. lets check my answer

Comment: Thank you ! that was the problem. I was using foreign key with references in both migrations (tickets and order_lines)  and as you said one is enough. Last question : Does it make a difference if a put the foreign key with reference in Ticket or Order_lines ? Thank again for all your answer.

Comment: perhaps this could be a good example of a circular reference error. To answer your question, note that a foreign key cannot reference a column that does not (yet) exists. Which of these 2 tables have records that are created first? The other table with the least priority or that you could consider optional should be the one holding the foreign key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move foreign key definitions to second function `Schema::table(...` or since you are creating constraints between multiple tables, add foreign keys in next migration, after creating all required tables.

Remember that, while creating foreign keys, **you need to have coresponding tables properly formed up**, in the first place.

As a side note, model relationships do not need to be created, while building your db structure. You can safely create them afterwards...

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.  gestion_concert_spectacle is the name of the database, I don't know why it's written "can't create the table...but I think the problem come from a foreign key. I follow your indications : I drop my DB and created another one with the same name, put all foreign key and references in comment, done php artisan migrate. All the table have been created with no problem, I took it off the comments and done php artisan migrate:refresh. I have the same error...

Comment: @bruno my idea was to move all foreign keys declarations to next/consequent migration, and indeed make sure that all these ids are unsigned.... So in your migrations create all tables first. Then create next migration and add foreign keys to that tables, or create new migration file for each table, to add foreign key only to that specifc table...

Answer (score 1):

I faced issues like this before. Simply change `$table->integer('order_line_id')->unsigned();` to `$table->unsignedInteger('order_line_id')`; same with all other foreign ids (order_id and ticket_id)